# Unable to bypass angular sanitize security

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

I have a wysiwyg editor (**angular-editor**):

```
<angular-editor [(ngModel)]="code" name="code"></angular-editor>
```

Below the editor I'm trying to use **ngx-highlightjs**:

```
<pre>
  <code [highlight]="code" [lineNumbers]="true"></code>
</pre>
```

So, when I type in editor something like `<p>test</p>`, I'd like code (ngModel) be `<p>test</p>` instead `&lt;p&gt;test&lt;/p&gt;` so it become highlighted in `<code></code>`.

I've tryed using a pipe:

```
transform(html: string): SafeHtml {
  return this.sr.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
}
```

It's not working and anyway the value can be HTML, JS, any language and probably multiple language so I cannot bypass both HTML and JS (I guess it because there are trustHTML and trustScript methods).

So, how `code` can be `<p>test</p>` (the answer should not cover only HTML by pass but any language, either `<script>...</script>`) instead `&lt;p&gt;test&lt;/p&gt`?

I think I cannot use DomSanitizer class because it cover HTML or Script, not both.

NB: I don't even care about security, only I will use the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to format code I want to be highlighted.

[image]

Comment: @boredbear153 first line of my original post ;) @kolkov/angular-editor

Comment: oh yeah, i assumed it to be an wrapper component. my bad, thanks for the reply.